# End Of Life for jQuery 3.2.1 version?

Tags: jquery

Is there any official documentation available mentioning the expiry / end of life for jQuery versions (3.2.1 in this case)

Thanks,
Amod

Comment: What do you expect would happen at the "end of life"? Some websites still use jQuery versions 1.x and they work.

Comment: V 1x and 2x just doesn't get patches anymore, unless a serious issue is found, where they might consider patching those versions anyway - so they are EOL in a sense- but they work fine.